# How to read JSON from URL with JQuery and select the one of key/values append to the selector in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am quite new to this, I have bean searching relative topics for days but with no luck.

The URL from the back-end is a pure JSON strings:

`{ "key 1":"val 1", "key 2":"val 2",... }`

I was trying to using the official sample to append one of the Value to the Modal body.

```
$.getJSON( "url", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", { //anyone can explain what is this <ul+/>?
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( ".Modal-body" );
});
```

But I can not avoid loop through from the whole string.

How to get just one key or val? like: key 2 or val 2 ?

Any helps or sample will be much appreciate!

Comment: <ul/> create element in pair <ul></ul>

Comment: Thanks @daremachine I did not know it can code like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this a little. Firstly `$.getJSON()` will deserialise the response to an object for you, so the use of `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` is redundant.

Secondly if all you want to read is one key from the resulting object you don't need a loop, you can access it directly. The only thing to note is that you will need to use bracket notation as the key names contain spaces. Try this:

```
$.getJSON('/yoururl', function(data) {
  var key1 = data['key 1'];
  console.log(key1); // = 'val 1'

  $('#yourSelector').append(key1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding: so thats why they put the dot with >> var key1 = data.key_1;